Crear "tarjetas" en runtime con Genexus
Quisiera saber si alguno sabe si hay alguna forma en Genexus que recorriendo los datos de una tabla, muestre en pantalla "cartas" dinamicamente.
O sea si tengo 3 registros me muestre tres "cartas o tarjetas" o como quieran llamarlo, pero si agrego o quito se refleje en tiempo de ejecución.
Espero haber sido claro.
Muchas gracias!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
